# How to hide a div if the url of anchor tag is empty using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, hide, anchor

This is the code

```
<div class="pdf_link">
    <a href="<%=getCurrentAttribut e('item','custitem_pdf_spec')%>" class="pdf">DOWNLOAD PDF</a>
</div>
```

i want to hide the whole div if the href of  tag dont have any url for pdf download.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy and short:

```
$("a[href='']").parent().hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('.pdf_link').has('a[href=""]').hide();
```

or

```
$('.pdf_link').filter(function(){
    return $.trim($(this).children('a').attr('href')) == '';
}).hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if($(".pdf_link a").attr("href")=="" || $(".pdf_link a").attr("href")=="#")
{
$(this).closest(".pdf_link").hide();
}
```